# Loading Wordpress Site Inside iframe won't allow users to login

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy, x-frame-options

I'm loading my wordpress website inside of an iframe.

However, on Chrome, I cannot login to the Worpdress site when it is inside the iframe. I've been pushed in the direction of a reverse proxy, but wondering if there are any other solutions?

I've tried the following:

It will load after changing the http headers, but the login issue still persists. I changed them to this:

```
proxy_cookies_flags ~ secure samesite=none;
add_header Set-Cookie "Path=/; Secure; SameSite=None;

add_header X-Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors https://examroom.ai";
add_header X-Content-Security-Policy "frame-src https://examroom.ai";
add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM https://examroom.ai";
```

Comment: Welcome! Probably better to ask this on [wordpress.se].